# Organizing tons of mp3's

Tags: linux

I have a giant library of mp3 and audio files that include songs, audiobooks, personal sound recordings, sound effects, etc.  I am completely overwhelmed by the options of having a "media library".  I would really like the ability to search and sort through the files (possibly from mp3 tags in the files themselves).  I don't trust applications like iTunes and Windows Media Player.  I want something stable and powerful.  I am a power user and do not mind some extra hacking to get a solution to fit my needs (okay, they are really "wants").

Anyway..here are some of my "wants":

- Build Playlists
- Play Playlists and remove songs from the list during playback
- Easily edit tags of the mp3 while it is playing (fix errors or add comments)
- Categorize (eg Audio book, song, etc)

Which technologies have users found useful?  Also which applications are junk not worth trying?  I use Linux and don't mind command-line tools, but would like a system to put it all together.

Comment: MediaMonkey is very highly rated as a music organizer, and currently I've yet to find anything approaching its level of power on Linux or otherwise. I believe it runs well in wine, but have yet to try it. Unfortunately I can't offer anything native -- I've searched but turned up nothing noteworthy.

Comment: I like Amarok < 2 for playback, but for bulk renaming / recognizing / moving files on harddisk I really like [Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardTagger)

Answer (score 0):

[Top iTunes alternatives for Linux](http://blogote.com/2010/linux-tips/top-itunes-alternatives-for-linux.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/wiki/Download).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but [Banshee](http://banshee.fm/) does a great job here.

[image: banshee screenshot]

Also, for multiple retags, [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) is a great help.

Comment: i know banshee fails hard for me on a large collection. I've had success with both mpd and subsonic past about 100,000 tracks.

Comment: @Sirex 100k? I wonder how much of these you actually ever listened to :p But no, I haven't tried banshee for that size of a collection. Did you try Banshee 2.0, too?

Answer (score 0):

[XMMS2](http://xmms2.org/wiki/Main_Page) (note the 2) is worth looking at if you want a console based system or cannot be bothered by large bloated media players like Amarok or Banshee.